# Wordpress menu items not showing in menu location?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

we are working on a WordPress website using one engine theme ,the menu items in the website are added from the admin dashboard using appearance->menus and added menu items, we added two items the two items showing neatly from the admin dashboard preview but come to the live website it is showing only one menu link that is HOME link , why it happens and what is the solution to fix this

Comment: Maybe you have some broken front-end code?

Comment: how to fix this

Comment: Use your programming knowledge or find normal programmers

Answer (score 1):

have u register your menu? if yes then create a menu name from the admin side after that u will get manage menu tab select your menu from select box and hit save

When you save finally your two menu the lower side checkbox should be checked by default then only will show the menu